# Rendering different templates in one outlet in ember.js

Tags: javascript, templates, ember.js

I have an ember application that allows you to create, edit and delete users as well as view a list of users. I made the app by following a tutorial (still learning ember) and my problem is that all of the CRUD pages load in different outlets. I want to have a list of users in the application `{{outlet}}`, then when I click on one user, for that user's individual details to be displayed in the same `{{outlet}}` as the list. If I click edit, I want an edit form to appear in the `{{outlet}}`, and on save I want the `{{outlet}}` to once again render the list of users. Can anybody tell me how I would go about doing this? Or suggest a better way of rendering things?

Here is my `router.js`:

```
App.Router.map(function(){
  this.resource('users', function(){
    this.resource('user', { path:'/:user_id' }, function(){
      this.route('edit');
    });
    this.route('create');
  });
});
```

And my templates:

Application Template:

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="application">

//This is where I want everything to render

      {{outlet}}

  </script>
```

Users Template

```
<script type = "text/x-handlebars" id = "users">

{{#link-to "users.create"}}Create New User {{/link-to}}


 <ul class="list-group">        
        {{#each user in controller}}
            <li class="list-group-item">            
               {{#link-to "user" user}}                                                
                    {{user.firstName}} {{user.lastName}}
                {{/link-to}}

            </li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul> 
//This is where the individual agent currently gets rendered, but it looks terrible
{{outlet}}

</script>
```

Individual User Template

```
<script type = "text/x-handlebars" id = "user">
<div class="user-profile">
 {{#if deleteMode}}
            <div class="confirm-box">
                <h5>Really?</h5>
                <button {{action "confirmDelete"}}> yes </button>
                <button {{action "cancelDelete"}}> no </button>
            </div>
            {{/if}}

  <h4>Name: {{firstName}} {{lastName}}</h4>
  <h4>Email: {{email}}</h4>


  <button {{action "edit"}}>Edit</button>
<button {{action "delete"}}>Delete</button>
</div>


 //This is where the edit form gets rendered, again looking dreadful
{{outlet}}

</script>
```

Edit User Template

```
<script type = "text/x-handlebars" id = "user/edit">


  <h5>First Name</h5>
  {{input value=firstName}}

  <h5>Last Name</h5>
  {{input value=lastName}}

  <h5>Email</h5>
  {{input value=email}}

<button {{action "save"}}> Save </button>

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is best to match the nesting of your routes with the nesting of your templates/outlets, as the rendering of the latter depends on the routes' hierarchy. So if you want to render the routes in the same `outlet` i.e. the initial `application outlet` then it is best not to nest these routes.

```
App.Router.map(function(){
  this.resource('users', function(){
    this.route('create');
  });
  this.resource('user', { path:'users/:user_id' }, function(){
      this.route('edit');
    });
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/oYiDIWe/1#/users

**EDIT** - *related to comments for user create/edit*

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/iBEBEso/1#/users

```
App.Router.map(function(){
  this.resource('users', function(){

  });
  this.resource('user', { path:'users/:user_id' }, function(){
      //this.route('edit');
    });
  this.route('users.create',{path:'users/create'});
  this.route('user.edit',{path:'users/:user_id/edit'});
});
```

Related documentation in http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/

Comment: Thanks, that's worked great for users and individual users! How can I do it for create/edit though?

Comment: @bookthief glad it worked. Indeed maybe create/edit was not that clear, please have a look at http://emberjs.jsbin.com/iBEBEso/1#/users , answer will also be updated.